# If $f,g:E \to \mathbb R$, $f\le g$ then $\max f \le \max g$

Tags: analysis

If $f,g:E \to \mathbb R$, $f\le g$ then $\max f \le \max g$ ($f,g$ are continuous)? If it is true, than how to prove it?

Comment: contradiction seems to work.

Comment: Was it mentioned somewhere that $E$ is compact?

Answer (score 0):

It is true assuming that $\max$ exists. The proof is to take max on the RHS first and have $f(x)\le \max g$ for all $x$. Then $\max f \le \max g$

If $\max$ is not guaranteed to exist, you may want to replace $\max$ with $\sup$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $x$, we have $f(x) \le g(x) \le \sup g$, and hence $\sup f \le \sup g$.

This has really nothing to do with functions as such, if you have sets $A,B$ with the property that for all $a \in A$, there exists some $b \in B$ such
that $a \le b$, then we have $\sup A \le \sup B$. The proof is exactly as above.